# What's the best way to have a single payer for my NFT site?

Tags: nft, payer

I am building an NFT platform where a list of wallets are allowlisted to mint a membership NFT. We want our platform to pay the fees, rent, etc. on minting. What's the best way to do this?

(currently all fees are being paid by the members)

Answer (score 2):

instead of them signing the transaction, create you wallet instace in the backend sign transaction with that wallet.and mint the nft to the User